# Pretty-printing JavaScript objects

Tags: haskell, pretty-print

I've chosen to center this question around JSON objects and [wl-pprint-annotated](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wl-pprint-annotated) ([here is the paper behind that library](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/prettier/prettier.pdf)) because they make it easy to have an MVCE, but my problem is not actually around pretty-printing *just* JSON objects and I am flexible for which pretty-printing library I use.

---

Consider the following simplified JavaScript object data type:

```
data Object = Object [(String, Object)]
            | String String
```

**How can I defined a pretty-printing function that wraps its output to multiple lines in the usual way?** What I mean by that is: the pretty-printed output should, whenever possible fit on one line. When that is not possible, I expect the outermost objects to start adding newlines before the inner ones.

Here is one attempt using [wl-pprint-annotated](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wl-pprint-annotated):

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedString #-}
import Text.PrettyPrint.Annotated.WL

prettyObject :: Object -> Doc a 
prettyObject (String str) = "\"" <> text str <> "\""
prettyObject (Object fields) = Union ("{" <+> hsep fields' <+> "}")
                                     ("{" <#> indent 2 (vsep fields') <#> "}")

   where
     fields' :: [Doc a]
     fields' = punctuate "," [ text key <> ":" <+> prettyObject val
                             | (key,val) <- fields ]
```

Now, some test cases.

```
ghci> o1 = Object [("key1", String "val1")]
ghci> o2 = Object [("key2", String "val2"), ("looooooooooong key3", String "loooooooooooong val3"),("key4", String "val4")]
ghci> o3 = Object [("key5", String "val5"), ("key6", o2), ("key7", String "val7")]
ghci> prettyObject o1
{ key1: "val1" }
ghci> prettyObject o2
{
  key2: "val2",
  looooooooooong key3: "loooooooooooong val3",
  key4: "val4"
}
ghci> prettyObject o3
{ key5: { key1: "val1" }, key6: {
  key2: "val2",
  looooooooooong key3: "loooooooooooong val3",
  key4: "val4"
}, key7: "val7" }
```

I would like the last output to instead be

```
{
  key5: { key1: "val1" },
  key6: {
    key2: "val2",
    looooooooooong key3: "loooooooooooong val3",
    key4: "val4"
  },
  key7: "val7"
}
```

I am looking for a solution which somehow fits with one of the existing pretty-printing libraries in Haskell (in reality, I'm pretty-printing *much* more than just a subset of JSON).

I am *not* looking for a solution which defines a `prettyObject :: Object -> String` - the whole point of this approach is that the rendering of the `Doc` depends on where it is in the big picture of what is being pretty-printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pretty print library you are using can already do this; (you have just told it to do a different thing!) generally this family (WL) of pretty printers handles this case pretty well.

Note the positioning of your `Union`:

```
prettyObject (Object fields) = Union <one line> <many line>
```

At the point in your text where you are logically making the choice to break, which is at the beginning of a key-value pair, you don't have a `Union` in your `Doc` structure. The choice is made at the point where a `{..}` enclosed block begins; and if you scrutinize the output, that is exactly what it gives you:

```
{ key5: { key1: "val1" }, key6: { ----- line break here
  key2: "val2",
```

You need a function to implement your desired logic for key-value pairs:

```
indent' k x = flatAlt (indent k x) (flatten x) 
prettyKVPair (k,v) = indent' 2 $ text k <> ":" <+> pretty v
```

`indent'` is like `indent`, but provides an explicit alternative which is not indented. `flatAlt` provides an alternative which is used when the text is flattened, and your text will be flattened by (you may have guessed) `flatten`. You also need to re-structure `prettyObject` accordingly:

```
prettyObject :: Object -> Doc a 
prettyObject (Object fields) = sep $ "{" : fields' ++ [ "}" ] where 
  fields' = punctuate "," $ map prettyKVPair fields
...
```

Note there is no explicit `Union`, but `sep = group . vsep` and `group = \x -> Union (flatten x) x`. You now have a union corresponding to logical choices about where you flatten your text.

The result:

```
>pretty o1
{ key1: "val1" }
>pretty o2
{
  key2: "val2",
  looooooooooong key3: "loooooooooooong val3",
  key4: "val4"
}
>pretty o3
{
  key5: "val5",
  key6: {
    key2: "val2",
    looooooooooong key3: "loooooooooooong val3",
    key4: "val4"
  },
  key7: "val7"
}
```

---

In response to the question in the comment, the way to provide a flat alternative is to use `flatAlt`, of course! The only issue here is you want to do this for a single element (the last one) of a list - but this is an issue with lists, not `Doc`. Feel free to use `Data.Sequence` or any other `Traversable`, with which most of the 'list-like' functions like `punctuate` work, if this is an operation you need a lot.

```
flattenedOf a b = flatAlt a (flatten b) # useful combinator

trailingSep _ [] = [] 
trailingSep s xs = as ++ [ (a <> s) `flattenedOf` a ]
  where as = init xs; a = last xs 

...
prettyObject (Object fields) = <unchanged> where 
  fields' = trailingSep "," $ <unchanged>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really an amazing answer/explanation.